# `error TS2307: Cannot find module` when using @types/ws with typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript

```
$ grep version node_modules/typescript/package.json 
  "version": "2.0.3"

$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
Version 2.0.3

$ npm install @types/ws
wechaty@0.4.0 /Users/zixia/git/wechaty
└── @types/ws@0.0.34 

$ cat t.ts 
import * as WebSocket from 'ws'
const ws = new WebSocket('https://api.wechaty.io')
console.log('ws')

$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --target es6 t.ts
t.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ws'.
```

if i use `tsc` without `--target es6`, it will work without any problem. but if i do so, I can't use `async`/`await` anymore.

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc t.ts # will be ok
```

what did i miss?

btw: typescript issue here - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a confirmed bug of typescript 2.0.3: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11103

passing `--moduleResolution node` would address the issue.